# Simple jQuery .show and hide div on "click"

Tags: jquery

I would like to simply show a div and hide it on click. This is what i have so far, but it's not working.

```
var jQueryslides = jQuery('.touchcarousel.tc-layout-1 .tc-desc h4, .touchcarousel');
var jQueryexc = jQuery('.cc_excerpt');

jQueryexc.hide();

jQueryslides.on('click', function(){

    jQuery('.tc-desc').css('height', '350px');
    jQueryexc.show();

});

jQuery('.cc_excerpt').on('click', function(){

    jQueryexc.hide();

});
```

Comment: Define "not working."  Where/how specifically does it fail?

Comment: @David when i click on .cc_excerpt, it doesn't hide the div.

Comment: Are there any errors on the JavaScript console?  Is jQuery even loaded?  Does the selector find the element(s) you expect when the code executes?  Is the click handler invoked at all?  When you step through the code in a debugger, what happens?  Please don't treat your code as an opaque box, you need to at least be willing to debug.

Comment: Is the `.cc_excerpt` inside the `.touchcarousel` by any chance? If so, the issue is probably that the `click` event is bubbling up and running `jQueryslides.click` so instantly re-displaying the excerpt. You would need to set `event.cancelBubble = true;` in `cc_excerpt.click`